# JavaScript Object Multiple Sorting

Tags: javascript

```js
ArrayObject = [{

0: {label: "117", objects: Array(1), toString: ƒ, status: 1}
1: {label: "118", objects: Array(1), toString: ƒ, status: 1}
2: {label: "156", objects: Array(1), toString: ƒ, status: 1}
3: {label: "164", objects: Array(1), toString: ƒ, status: 1}
4: {label: "asterisk", objects: Array(1), toString: ƒ, status: 1}

]
```

I have been trying that I would like to sort multiple values like firstly * value should comes first index and secondly It should work as normal sorting. Is there any way to make it work.

Here the **actual scenario**,

```
ArrayObject { 

label: "Text1",
label: "text2",
label: "123",
label: "*"

}
```

**expected like**

```
ArrayObject { 

    label: "*",
    label: "123",
    label: "Text1",
    label: "text2"

 }
```

I have tried this,

```
ArrayObject.sort(function(x,y){return x == "asterisk" ? -1 : y == "asterisk" ? 1 : 0;});
```

It works great but in other places normal sorting is not working properly

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I have facing the issue, given sample scenario.

Comment: So? Please make an attempt yourself.

Comment: This is not working...

Comment: Please post your data with valid syntax, e.g. as a JSON structure. It's unclear what `ArrayObject` and `label` are supposed to be.

Comment: updated in post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ArrayObject = [{
    label: "*"
  },
  {
    label: "123"
  },
  {
    label: "Text1"
  },
  {
    label: "text2"
  }
]
var answer = [
  ...ArrayObject.filter(x => x.label == '*'),
  ...ArrayObject.filter(x => x.label != '*').sort((a, b) => a.label >= b.label ? 1 : -1)
]
console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator to move `*` to the beginning of the array.

```js
let data = [{ label: "*" }, { label: "123" }, { label: "Text1" }, { label: "text2" } ];
data.sort((a,b) => a.label == "*" ? -1 : b.label == "*" ? 1 : a.label.localeCompare(b.label, undefined, {numeric: true}));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, use your `{` and `[` wisely. This is an array having 1 object which have 5 fields each being an object of 4 fields. In other words array has only 1 element. No reason to sort 1 element.

```
ArrayObject = [{

0: {label: "117", objects: Array(1), toString: ƒ, status: 1},
1: {label: "118", objects: Array(1), toString: ƒ, status: 1},
2: {label: "156", objects: Array(1), toString: ƒ, status: 1},
3: {label: "164", objects: Array(1), toString: ƒ, status: 1},
4: {label: "asterisk", objects: Array(1), toString: ƒ, status: 1}

}];
```

You probably mean this which is an array of 5 objects. Now sorting is reasonable.

```
ArrayObject = [

 {label: "117"},
 {label: "118"},
 {label: "156"},
 {label: "164"},
 {label: "asterisk"}

];
```

Now coming to the sorting. By default Arrays are sorted according to the natural order of its elements. If element is an object then we mostly want to provide our own sort logic.

Strings are sorted according to the lexical ordering of there characters, that's true but more true is that in fact there ascii codes are being compared and as result

`"c++"` will always be greater than `"Java"` , `"C#"` or even `"Python"`

because the ascii code of lowercase '`c`' in "c++" is greater than the ascii codes of `'J'` `'C'` `'P'`

If you had an Array of these strings you will sort in ascending order as below

```
var languages= ["C#", "c++", "Java", "Python"];
languages.sort();

//Output
[ "C#", "Java", "Python", "c++" ]
```

Now in your case you have an Array of Objects where each object has a string field and you want to sort on that field according to your requirement. To do that you need to write a boolean [function expression](https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2015/javascript-lambda-and-arrow-functions/) as an argument to sort method that will define your sort logic. Lets forget your requirement for now and sort according to natural order of strings as above.

```
var languages = [
 {name: "C#"},
 {name: "c++"},
 {name: "Java"},
 {name: "Python"}  
];

languages.sort( (a,b) => {
        return a.name > b.name;
    });

//Output
[
 {name: "C#"},
 {name: "Java"},
 {name: "Python"},
 {name: "c++"}  
]
```

Suppose someone mistakenly told you that `"Javascript"` was the very first language and thus is the greatest of all. It means keep `"Javascript"` the greatest and sort other elements based on natural ordering , then your sort logic will be

```
var languages = [
 {name: "C#"},
 {name: "c++"},
 {name: "Java"},
 {name: "Javascript"},
 {name: "Python"}  
];

languages.sort((a,b)=>{  
    if(a.name=="Javascript")
        return true;
    else
        if(b.name =="Javascript")
            return false;
    else
        return a.name > b.name

});

//Output
[
 {name: "C#"},
 {name: "Java"},
 {name: "Python"},
 {name: "c++"},
 {name: "Javascript"}  
]
```

and when you come to your senses

```
 languages.sort((a,b)=>{  
        if(a.name=="Javascript")
            return false;
        else
            if(b.name =="Javascript")
                return true;
        else
            return a.name > b.name

    });

//Output
[
 {name: "Javascript"} ,
 {name: "C#"},
 {name: "Java"},
 {name: "Python"},
 {name: "c++"}

]
```

By returning `true` when `a.name` is ***"Javascript"*** and `false` when `b.name` is ***"Javascript"*** we are telling the sort algorithm to always swap `a` to the right when `a.name` is ***"Javascript"*** and don't swap when `b.name` is ***"Javascript"***. If both `a.name` and `b.name` are not ***"Javascript"*** then just keep the natural ascending ordering which is the result from `a.name > b.name`

Exact opposite will happen if you reverse the `true` and `false` as in the second version of the code. That is why ***"Javascript"*** is at the first index.

Hope I have enlightened you.

Answer (score -1):

My proposition:

```js
const myArray = [
  {label: "Text1"},
  {label: "abc"},
  {label: "*"},
  {label: "text2"},
  {label: "123"}
];

const sorted = myArray.sort((a,b) => a.label === '*' ? -1 : a.label.localeCompare(b.label));
console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: That's not enough. What if `b.label` is `*`?

Comment: Not working... I have tried this "return x == "asterisk" ? -1 : y == "asterisk" ? 1 : 0;}" "*" positioned top but other default sorting is not working.